# Can I get a list of contacts without created case?

Tags: contacts, civicase, contact-view

I'm wondering if it's possible to get a list of contacts without a created case (even if the case is closed).

We have a workflow when some beneficiaries "apply" to be "active beneficiaries" to receive companion from volunteers. Then, after an evaluation, the CiviCRM users open a case to that beneficiary to follow up their activities. How ever, we need to know how much and which contacts in that "active beneficiaries" doesn't have a case created, to don't lose any contact that could be unattended.

I tried with advanced search, but this is a negative criteria with an "empty" field. I mean, this should be "Contacts in X group AND Not in a case?

Thanks for your feedback,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pete's answer should work but I think you can do it faster if you go to CiviReport - Case Reports and run the Contact Demographics Report and on the Filters tab set "Cases?" to exclude cases.

Comment: Thanks so much! this solution it's exactly what I need because I also need apply filters by groups. ¡Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might do it for you or point you in a direction

Create a Group of All Contacts (A)

Create a Group of All Contacts who have ever had a Case (B)

Use the Custom Search: Include/Exclude Groups and set it to A-B